# How to call a function of a jQuery plugin (creating new plugin)?

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

I'm creating a jQuery plugin for one of my projects and I was wondering what's the best way to go about this.  I need to be able to call a function on the plugin from outside the plugin, at any time.  For example, an event outside the plugin happens, and I want to say "plugin, do this".  I've played around a bit and this works, but doesn't feel right.

In my plugin:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.update = function(element) {
    updateTable(element);   // this is a function within the plugin 
};
```

To call this function, I do this:

```
$('#someID').myPlugin.update();
```

This works, but the element param is null and I only have one element currently for this plugin.  I think it would fail with multiple elements, since the function searches that element for specific children.  What's the proper way to be able to to call a function within the plugin from outside it, and have it effect the element its attached to?  I'm following this tutorial: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the elements selected are in the `this` variable. The elements are not passed to the function through your element parameter.
So for instance:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.update = function(){
    updateTable(this);
}
```

should work perfectly.
If you want to get the jQuery object associated with the selector just do

```
selector = $(this);
```

`selector` is the jQuery object that is the selector.

Answer (score 1):

The element argument should be undefined because you're passing nothing to the update() function. If you want to refer to the contents of the jQuery object try:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin.update = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    updateTable(this);
  }
};
```

Also, you should apply your plugin to the jQuery object, not $. That article is giving you bad advice in that regard. Take a look at [jQuery Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: Actually, the article discusses closure, but @Ryan seems not to have been there yet.